# How to upload to a new folder in Amazon S3 Bucket?

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I am building a page that the user can upload the file chosen to a new folder in S3 bucket which will be created when the user uploaded the file.

The user will enter name of the new folder in the textbox given, then the user will select the file to be uploaded, when the user click upload button, S3 bucket will create a new folder and upload the file in the new created folder.

Code below is the code that i tried. I have tried this

```
     'conditions' => array(
     array('bucket' => $my_bucket),  
     array('acl' => 'public-read'),  
     array('starts-with' => $key, '/'),  
     array('starts-with', '$Content-Type', ''),
     array('body' => ''),
     array('success_action_status' => '201'),  
     array('x-amz-credential' => implode('/', array($access_key, $short_date, $region, 's3', 'aws4_request'))),  
     array('x-amz-algorithm' => 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'),  
     array('x-amz-date' => $iso_date),  
     array('x-amz-expires' => ''.$presigned_url_expiry.''),
```

but i couldnt get it. i hope you guys can help me on this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. You can upload the file to a 'non-existent' folder and the folders will 'appear'. Then, if the file is deleted, the folders will 'disappear'.

This is because the filename (`Key`) of each Amazon S3 object contains the full path. Folders are derived from the paths (called `CommonPrefixes`) and are there more as a convenience (eg for listing files in a folder) rather than being required.

If you *really* need to create a folder, you can create a zero-length object with the same name (Key) as the folder. This will make the folder 'appear' (even though it doesn't exist).

**Bottom line:** Don't bother making folders. Just upload the files to where you want them. Trust me.

Comment: hi thank you for the answer. but can you explain more on how to really create a folder.I get your point but i just want to learn how to. Thanks

Comment: Not much more to say... You can either click "Create Folder" in the S3 management console, or create a zero-length object with the same name as the folder. It does the same thing. To "create" such a file, you could either use the API, or simply copy an empty file to that name in the bucket.